# Adding views to a UITabBarController's root view in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, interface-builder

I have a subclass of UITabBarController that adds custom views to the controller's root view. This happens programmatically with a call to `[self.view addSubview:customView]`.

Is there a way to represent this with Interface Builder? I wasn't able to drag a view into the UITabBarController.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a **UITableViewController** with xib your **viewController's self.view** is your **UITableView** like below that's why you are not be able to drag a view into table view.
[image]

For that just add a view map that view as your **self.view** drag the tableview into newly added view like below. Now your custom view can be added to tableview's superview.

[image]

after adding the custom view
[image]

Hope this would help you.